# Are there languages which have h following a consonant, that contrasts with aspiration?

Tags: phonology, ipa, aspiration

I am working on a conscript and want to make sure I can handle all of Earth's languages. In some Indian languages they have the aspirated consonants like `bh` like `bhavya`. It is basically a breathy `b`. But other languages like Swahili have `mh` like [mhenga](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mhenga#Swahili), in which the `m` and `h` are pronounced separately. First tangential question  is, how is that second case represented in IPA?

Second, the main question, is are there languages which have sound-sequences of a consonant followed by a regular `h`, like `bh-`, `dh-`, `th-`, `tʃh`, or `dʒh`, etc.? By that I mean, the Indian languages described use that syntax for defining *aspiration*, but it's not like `b-havya`, with the `b` and `h` pronounced separately. It's more like the b is extended to have breath. But if I had a writing system which put `<consonant><h>`, that would have to mean one or the other, not both. So `mhenga` would be a breathy/aspirated `m` for example, instead of `m-henga`.

To summarize, how do I think about this? How do you write both cases in IPA? Are there cases of consonants followed by an `h` sound that isn't just aspiration? If so, what are some brief examples. I don't think I've come across a case outside of `m` and `n` an `h` sound follows. But I may have just overlooked that.

What if I wanted to say `b-havya`, how would I write that in IPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPA distinguishes [bʰ] and [bh], the former being aspiration of [b], the latter being a cluster "b plus h". As for "mh", the diaresis-below diacritic serves as the indicator of a breathy nasal, whish is what "mh" is in a number of languages. However, in Swahili, the correct transcription is [m̩h], e.f. [m̩haŋga] "aardvark" – a trisyllabic word with a syllabic [m] plus a second syllable [ha] (likewise *mhenga*).

No language has yet been reported that contrast aspiration of a stop versus a stop-h cluster. In various works, Golston and Kehrein have used this fact as an argument that in principle there can be no contrast, because aspiration (also glottalization) is not a property of the individual segment, it is a property of the prosodic node (onset, coda) that dominates them.

Comment: What does `a cluster "b plus h"` sound like then? Is it the same thing as the `m + h` (with that little line below)? What is that little line below called so I can find it online? I don't get why you need a syllabic consonant marker.

Comment: Your question is about phonology, what things sound like is about phonetics. I'd start with the question of what bʰ, pʰ sound like – it varies across languages. Certifiable examples of C+h clusters arise in Semitic languages and include s+h. Compare "latex" vs "late hex" for a start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether your question is specific to `bh`, or, as in the introductory sentence, covers "all languages".

You mention "sound sequences", and reading your comment "what does 'b plus h' sound like", I first thought about "[abhor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abhor)".

In English, can distinguish the pronunciation of aspirated `t` vs `t+h` in "at home" and "a tome"?

In German, you have `p+h` in "[abholen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abholen)" vs aspirated `p` in "[Apostel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apostel)".

It's all a question of how you define "sound sequence" and "constrast".